# Some logical business in controller or all in model [MVC] PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I've been building a system with MVC pattern, and im stuck with the implementation of methods.

In my application, a company can get rating by the users. The company can or not exists in my application, so before the insert the rating the company have to exists in database.

My question is: have i to implement all the business logic in model or some validations in controller?

CONTROLLER

1. check if have `$_POST`;
2. check if company exists;
3. if not exists execute `insert()` from Company model and return the inserted id;
4. insert the rating with the `$_company_id` (Rating model);

## **OR**

CONTROLLER

1. Check if have `$_POST`
2. execute `insert()` from Rating model with company parameters

RATING MODEL

1. Check if company exists;
2. if not exists execute `insert()` from Company model and return the inserted id;
3. insert the rating with the `$_company_id` (Rating model);

Comment: in second method, u shud remove 2nd point.

Comment: if i remove 2nd point in the second method, the company will not be inserted in the db, and the rating can't inserted too... (tks for the edit)

Comment: Validation and implementation of business logic is done in the Model.  No matter where a change originates, Model, View or Controller it will need to be validated,  and in your case business logic will need to be run.  The final destination is the Model and that is where this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

What MVC means and what we have learned so far.

```
M(Model)      -> Used to perform database operations.
V(Views)      -> viewing the data in browser.
C(Controller) -> handle model and view.
```

So i would say, in your case, go ahead with 2nd option.

If you have any validations to be done, do it in controller.